# how can I run gatsby serve as a service in centos?

Tags: linux, server, gatsby

or is there a third framework to deploy it? Now I use `gatsby serve` to run it in centos, but the server shuts down after I exit console window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally for this sort of thing there are a few ways to do it, among which are:

- the simplest one is appending an `&` after the command and running `disown` before exiting your terminal session, `&` makes it so that the process runs in the background and disown separates the process from it's parent so that it doesn't close when you exit. If you use this method I would recommend forwarding the output of the command to a file so that you can later review it after your session has closed, for example `gatsby serve & > access.log`
- a better solution is using programs such as [screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) or [tmux](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tmux) which create a terminal session that can be "closed" and reopened after, please take a look at the linked man page, or run `man screen` (or man `tmux`) on your system to see how to use them as this is beyond the scope of this question.

The best solution however is however something integrated in gatsby: the build command. This generates a standalone node.js application that can be deployed on a remote server, you would build your application and setup a server such as nginx for this

Comment: I see,  it's a static website since build, so I can use any web server to deploy it, thanks!